# Drupal function to convert node into Json object

Tags: 8

I would like to know if any drupal function is readily available which converts the node object into Json object so that i can return it in the menu callback function in Ajax call.

thanks,
Ahmad

Answer (score 1):

To return on menu callback function in Ajax call you can use [drupal_json_output()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_json_output/7), you can use [this function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.pages.inc/function/user_autocomplete/7) as an example.

On that exampe you can see that you only need to call drupal_json_output() function with the object as the parameter, there's no need to return anything from your callback function.

If you need to convert the Drupal node object into JSON object to be returned on a function, you could consider to use [drupal_json_encode()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_json_encode/7)

Answer (score 0):

Try: drupal_json_output($var = NULL)

Comment: I tried but it only returns "False" as a return value

Comment: Because you'd need `drupal_json_output($node);` or other similar var to output.